# Can't write range based for with non-member begin and end functions

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, g++, bitboard

I'm writing a code that uses bitboards. since iterating on all bits of a bitboard is pretty common action, I decided to write some iterator class, and to use c++0x's range based loops.
However, g++ (version 4.6.3) tell me that there is not matching function for `begin` or `end`.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>

class bitscan {
    uint64_t mask;
public:
    bitscan(uint64_t m) : mask(m) {}
    bool operator!=(bitscan it) const {return mask!=it.mask;}
    bitscan &operator++() {mask&=(mask-1);return *this;}
    int operator*() {return __builtin_ctzl(mask);}
};

bitscan begin(uint64_t m) {return m;}
bitscan end(uint64_t m) {return 0;}

int main() {
    uint64_t num=49;
    for (int i : num) std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

The error:

```
err.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
err.cpp:18:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(long unsigned int&)’
err.cpp:18:15: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/initializer_list:86:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::begin(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&)
err.cpp:18:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘end(long unsigned int&)’
err.cpp:18:15: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/initializer_list:96:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::end(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&)
```

If I replace the loop by the line: `for (auto it=begin(num);it!=end(num);++it) std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;`
It works fine.

What is my mistake?

Comment: It's bitboard. for example, 49 is {0,4,5} (since 49==(1<<0)+(1<<4)+(1<<5) )

Comment: @chris : `bitscan` is the iterator type, `int` is the result of dereferencing that iterator.

Comment: @ildjarn, My bad. I thought the `begin` and `end` were taking `bitscan` arguments for some reason.

Comment: @chris : They need to in order to fix the OP's problem, so you're not that far off. :-]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the range-based for statement, the `begin` and `end` nonmember functions are only looked up via argument-dependent lookup<sup>(*)</sup> (C++11 §6.5.4/1).  This means that they will only be found in a namespace associated with the argument type (C++11 §3.4.2/2).

A fundamental type, like `uint64_t`, has no associated namespaces, so no `begin` or `end` will ever be found for it.  You'll need to create a class type to wrap the `uint64_t` so that nonmember `begin` and `end` functions may be found via argument-dependent lookup.

---

(*)  Note:  There are actually three ways that `begin` and `end` may be found, but this is the only way that applies to your scenario.  There are also special cases for arrays and for classes with member functions named `begin` and `end`.

Comment: So I have to wrap it in class? Is there any simple solution?

Comment: @asaelr That's the simple solution. Also, that's the *non-evil* solution.

Comment: @asaelr : `bitscan` already does that, so why would that be a problem?

Comment: @ildjarn bitscan doesn't know about bitwise operation, which I really need. maybe the simple solution is `for (int i:bitscan(num))`

Comment: @asaelr : And change `begin` and `end` to take `bitscan`, yes.

Comment: @ildjarn or (maybe) even better - I can make them member functions.

Comment: Do you know why the Standard does not prescribe unqualified lookup followed by ADL for non-array/non-class types? That would also solve the OP's question.